# How do split the values of a string from JOptionpane.showInput

Tags: java, time, split, joptionpane

My assignment requires to prompt from JOptionPane the message "Enter the time as hh:mm:ss"
From that input, how do I assign the values to my variables, hh, mm, and ss?

I tried splitting it as a string but it wont work because it hasnt been initialized yet. Help please? Im really new to java.

Comment: Show us the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

```
    String hh, mm, ss;
    String time = "12:01:54";
    String[] tmp = time.split(":");

    hh = tmp[0];
    mm = tmp[1];
    ss = tmp[2];

    System.out.println("Hours: " + hh + " Minutes: " + mm + " Seconds: " + ss);
```

Assuming your input is a string and you want your values stored as strings.